# Can I encode and decode a JSON on the GPU using MetalKit?

Tags: ios, json, swift, macos, metalkit

I have this situation where my database is a huge JSON, to a point that decoding and encoding it takes too long and my user experience is harmed.

I am syncing my DB constantly with a device that is communicating via BLE, and the DB gets bigger with time.

I used MetalKit in the past to speed up image filtering, but I am not a pro metal programmer and do not have the tools to determine whether I can achieve decoding/encoding my JSON using metal.

Comment: "to a point that decoding and encoding it takes too long and my user experience is harmed." Sounds like a good candidate for a background thread, no?

Comment: it is on a background thread, but sometimes the user needs to wait to get the updated db after making some changes. using cache helps but i rather have a full db integration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tasks that can be improved via GPU are the ones that can be parallelized. Since the GPU has many more cores than a CPU, a task that can be divided into smaller tasks (like image processing) are ideal for the GPU.  The encoding and decoding of JSON is something that needs a lot of serial processing and in that scenario you should go to the CPU.

I can not see how you can efficiently parallelize the serialization and deserialization of a JSON. Maybe if your JSON has an array with lots of small elements (all with the same structure), maybe in that particular scenario using the GPU can improve the performance.

Comment: thank you sir, this helps me understand the situation better.

Comment: In addition to needing to parallelize an algorithm in order to benefit from running it on a GPU, most GPUs are highly optimized for [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) computations (Same instruction, multiple data) where all the compute units run the same instruction at the same time, but on different data. Their caching mechanism doesn't do very well when each compute unit runs a different execution path, and they slow down dramatically.

Comment: There is some interesting work going on to leverage SIMD for JSON decoding. [Mison](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/mison-vldb17.pdf) (paper), [simdjson](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson)  (C++ impl), [simdjson-go](https://github.com/minio/simdjson-go) (Golang impl). It focuses primarily on AVX2, but the idea is that you use SIMD instructions to build an index (tape) of all the relevant control points in the JSON document to reduce parsing time.